# Update based on sequence/rank in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, rank

Table looks like this:

```
create table #rankme (rankmeid int identity(1000, 1) primary key, 
                      step int null, checkvalue int null)

insert into #rankme values ( 10 , 1 )
insert into #rankme values ( 15 , null )
insert into #rankme values ( 20 , null )
insert into #rankme values ( 40 , null )

select * from #rankme order by step,checkvalue
```

Taking `step` as a parameter, I am trying to find out if the requested `checkvalue` for the one before the `step` I asked for is null.

So I want to select `where step=20` and get `NULL`.

And I want to select `where step=15` and get a `1`.

I was trying to come up with something based on "rank-1" but so far no cigar.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @step int = 15

select top(1) R.checkvalue
from #rankme as R
where R.step < @step
order by R.step desc
```